# Python constructing a class that uses a function from within the same class

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to get a construct a class that calls a function from within the same class but I'm having trouble doing so.

I've had a look at:

[Python function pointers within the same Class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20381904/python-function-pointers-within-the-same-class)

But I've had no luck with the approach presented. I've created this simple example:

```
#### Libraries ####
# Third Party Libraries  
import numpy as np

#### Defines the activation functions ####
class sigmoid_class(object):
    def __init__(self, z):
        self.z = z

    def activation_fn(self):
        """The sigmoid function"""
        return 1.0/(1.0+np.exp(-self.z))

    def prime(self):
        """The derivative of the sigmoid function"""
        return activation_fn(self.z)*(1-activation_fn(self.z))

a = sigmoid_class(0)
print(a.prime())
```

when I test with `print(a.activation_fn(0))` I get the desired output, but when I try `print(a.prime())

```
I get `NameError: name 'activation_fn' is not defined
```

I'm not sure how to fix this so that it functions properly

Comment: use `self.activation_fn()`
activation_fn is a member function of the class, so you need to give it the class instance (which is self) in order to call it.

Comment: `self.activation_fn(self.z)*(1-self.activation_fn(self.z))`

Comment: I'm wondering whether the argument shouldn't be self -- not self.z as activation_fn signature is just self

Comment: @Keozon:  Actually that should be `self.activation_fn()`.  `activation_fn` doesn't take the z value as argument - it looks it up from `self`

Comment: @MartinBonner RIght, that's what I get for not looking close enough. Edited.

Comment: yes, all that is needed is `self.activation()*(1-self.activation())` I didn't read closely enough

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It should actually be:

```
def prime(self):
    """The derivative of the sigmoid function"""
    return self.activation_fn()*(1-self.activation_fn())
```

Note that `activation_fn` does not need to be passed the `z` value as well - it looks that up from `self`.

Answer (score 3):

So combining both points:

```
def prime(self):
    """The derivative of the sigmoid function"""
    return self.activation_fn()*(1-self.activation_fn())
```

`activation_fn` finds self.z for itself

Answer (score 2):

```
def prime(self):
    """The derivative of the sigmoid function"""
    return self.activation_fn(self.z)*(1-self.activation_fn(self.z))
```

Or so. note the `self.activation_fn` instead of just `activation_fn`.

Answer (score 1):

The comments are correct, you need reference `self.` because `activation_fn` is not defined in the scope of the method itself, and your method also doesn't take in any arguments.